# Recursive code returns None

Tags: python, recursion, return, nonetype

I really do not understand, why the code

```
def isIn(char, aStr): 
    ms = len(aStr)/2
    if aStr[ms] == char:
        print 'i am here now'
        return True
    elif char>aStr[ms] and not ms == len(aStr)-1:
        aStr = aStr[ms+1:]
    elif char <aStr[ms] and not ms == 0:
        aStr = aStr[0:ms]
    else:
        return False
    isIn(char, aStr)

print isIn('a', 'ab')
```

does keep on returning None. it prints 'i am here now', but it does not return True, just as the next line says. Why?

Comment: Maybe a `return isIn(char, aStr)` for the last line of the function? Right now it's falling off the end of the function without returning anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want a `return` on the last line:

```
return isIn(char, aStr)
```

Without it, the function simply returns `None` when it terminates without seeing a `return`.

Comment: Jepp. Did not see it. And i really tried hard. Thank you!